# Check who pushed the commit in mercurial HG

Tags: mercurial

Example scenario:

```
revision #100 - user1 makes a commit on DEV branch in 2017-01-01
revision #101 - user2 cherry picked user1's commit to master branch (hg graft -r 100) in 2017-01-02
```

hg log:

```
changeset:101
user: user1
date: 2017-01-01
summary: message 100

changeset:100
user: user1
date: 2017-01-01
summary: message 100
```

But how would I know user2 pushed revision #101?

Comment: Check the log of the site that host yor repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot (besides what Lasse suggest in his comment).

Consider:

```
touch a; hg add a; hg commit -m 'Add a as myself'
touch b; hg add b; hg commit -m 'Add b as you' --user you@foo.com
hg update 0
hg branch stable
hg graft --user 3rd@bar.com --force 1


hg log --graph

@  changeset:   2:3078a4888a8a
|  branch:      stable
|  tag:         tip
|  parent:      0:f7fa0d60eaf2
|  user:        3rd@bar.com
|  date:        Fri Apr 28 20:07:35 2017 +0200
|  summary:     Add b as you
|
| o  changeset:   1:e12471b861d6
|/   user:        you@foo.com
|    date:        Fri Apr 28 20:07:35 2017 +0200
|    summary:     Add b as you
|
o  changeset:   0:f7fa0d60eaf2
   user:        This Is Me me@me.com
   date:        Fri Apr 28 20:06:42 2017 +0200
   summary:     Add a as myself
```

If you think about it, it is less shocking than what is seems (I am not saying it is not a problem, mind you).

Mercurial has an [extension to perform PGP signatures](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/GpgExtension) which might help, but not after the fact and requires a certain setup.

To have detailed explanation, have a look at [CommitSigningPlan](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/CommitSigningPlan), although I don't know the status.

To my knowledge, [monotone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_(software)) was a distributed VCS system designed to solve this kind of problems, I am not sure whether it is still developed.

I would finish with a philosophical observation: if a project has to protect itself from this kind of problems (an authorised developer impersonating another), then maybe that project has other problems... Again, this doesn't mean that authenticating a commit is not important.